# Implementing an automatic "playlist" of Pure Data and Processing files

Tags: javascript, java, html, puredata

I apologize first for asking a quite unspecific problem. But I have so little clue and so little time that I really don't know where to start looking.

I'm a student in an introductory computational art class. We will have a final exhibition in 48 hours. I just realized everyone's works written in Pure Data or Processing have to be stored in a single PC and are supposed to be automatically displayed full-screen in loops. I was asked to implement the "playlist" but the only language I actually 'kinda' know is Processing. So all I have right now are some very naive ideas, which I don't even know if make sense or not:

1. I heard html5 canvas is quite powerful. Is it possible to use it as a front end to import .pd and .pde?
2. I also heard there is a certain tool (it somehow magically disappeared from my Google radar ... when I need it of course) to import Processing .pde to Pure Data, but it only operates in OSX systems. Is it possible to do something similar in Windows?
3. Is it possible to just use Java or C++ or something to open the artworks one at a time and automatically set them to fullscreen? But I've never done anything like this before. Actually I don't even know Java or Javascript at all...
4. Is there a better way to do what I want?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's doable for different processing sketches in processing and different Pure Data (and in your case GEM I suppose) patches in Pure Data respectively. However it is not (easily) done for a mix of both. I'd suggest you implement the loops in their respective languages and then make a bash script that brings either window in the foreground. It's a bit of a hack, but considering your situation probably as good as it gets.